# What is the better way to do a graphics module in my game

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

I'm refactoring a lot of stuff in my game,
And through [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105543/creating-items-in-a-game) it's come to my understanding the I'm making the graphic module entirely wrong. And by that, I mean making the all modules know the UI instead of making the UI know all modules.

[GitHub to the game code](https://github.com/gioragutt/training/tree/master/ModuloZero)

Btw: the class is obviously not finished, it has some old stuff that I checked (Like `Texture2D PlayerHealthTexture` and so on)

---

Currently, my UI is a static class that is something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace ModuloFramework.UI
{
    public delegate void UIDrawEventHandler(SpriteBatch spriteBatch);

    public static class UI
    {
        private static Dictionary<Color, Texture2D> ColorTextureRepository { get; set; }

        public static Texture2D GetColorTexture(Color color, GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        {
            if (ColorTextureRepository.ContainsKey(color))
                return ColorTextureRepository[color];
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, 1, 1);
            tex.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { color });
            ColorTextureRepository[color] = tex;
            return tex;
        }

        public static SpriteFont Font { get; set; }

        public static Texture2D PlayerHealthTexture { get; set; }

        public static event UIDrawEventHandler DrawingEvent;

        public static void SubscribeToUIDraw(UIDrawEventHandler handler)
        {
            DrawingEvent += handler;
        }

        public static void UnsubscribeFromUIDraw(UIDrawEventHandler handler)
        {
            DrawingEvent -= handler;
        }

        public static void Initialize(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        {
            ColorTextureRepository = new Dictionary<Color, Texture2D>();
        }

        public static void LoadContent(ContentManager manager)
        {
            Font = manager.Load<SpriteFont>("UI/MainFont");
        }

        public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            if (spriteBatch != null)
                DrawingEvent?.Invoke(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And, whenever I want something to draw on the UI, I do something like this:

```
public ItemBehavior()
{
    UI.SubscribeToUIDraw(PrintUi);
    isDrawn = false;
}

protected override void BehaviorImplementation(IUnit destinationPlayer)
{
    Debug.Print("Behavior test print");
    isDrawn = !isDrawn;
}

private void PrintUi(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    if (!isDrawn) return;
    spriteBatch.DrawString(UI.Font, string.Format("Test"), new Vector2(20, 50),
        Color.Black);
}
```

---

I want to know what's a better way to do that UI module.
For example, if I have an Inventory class that's supposed to have a visual representation on the UI, do I make a Draw() method in the Inventory class, or do I make a DrawInventory(Inventory inventory) method in the UI class?

---

Also, should I make a IDrawingEngine interface and have UI become a singleton that implements that interface, as recommended in the CodeReview post?
If I do that, and say I follow the second method(having UI know other modules), How would that interface be useful to me outside of the UI class itself?

---

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This a very open question and my first recommendation is to go and look at home WPF and Winforms do their rendering. I also recommend picking up a copy of the Unreal Engine SDK and looking at how they have structured the UI. There are some interesting ideas out there.

### A fundamental note

This isn't a new problem. People have spent a lot of time solving it already. Be inspired by their results! Is there an open source library you can integrate?

### The issue at hand

Each item on the screen should be able to function alone and will have a different graphical representation. Separate the different UI elements into classes. You will probably want a base class for the basic UI support - `Render()` etc. Your Inventory should be its own class.

The reason you can an interface is so that you can change the UI later *if you want to*. Perhaps you have two versions of the UI and you want to swap them in and out for performance testing! Static things prevent you from doing that.

Comment: I AM using a library already, it's MonoGame. It has XNA's libraries.

Comment: I just want to have something that's general enough for my needs and specific enough for my game itself, but for that I need to know how to do the specific stuff.